# Hybrid/double file entry for image

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, image-uploading

I have this javascript code below, where i want to make a hybrid entry method for an image file: dropping it and selecting by the file explorer.

The drop work perfectly, but if you try to upload a file using file explorer it doesn't show. I think is something inside `imgLoad()` because is not loading when i run it in the change event, no matter how i putted (even using different function call methods).

```
var obje=document.getElementById('toDrop');
var fileDoor=document.getElementById('fileImg');
obje.ondragover=function(ev) { ev.preventDefault();}
obje.ondrop=function imgLoad(eve) {
  eve.preventDefault();
  var fil=new FileReader();
  fil.onload=function(ev) { document.getElementById('toDrop').style.backgroundImage="url('"+ev.target.result+"')";
 }
   fil.readAsDataURL(eve.dataTransfer.files[0]);
  }
  fileDoor.onchange=imgLoad();
```

Demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/vtsvr4sa/1/

Answer (score 1):

`imgLoad` is not a globally defined function at Javascript at Question. You are also calling `imgLoad` immediately at `fileDoor.onchange=imgLoad()` instead of referencing the function `fileDoor.onchange=imgLoad`.

`change` event does not have a `.dataTransfer` property. Handle both `event.dataTransfer.files` or `event.target.files` within `imgLoad` handler using OR `||` operator.

Adjust `HTML` to use `<input type="file">` element as `drop` event target. Set `<input type="file">` element `CSS` to same `width` and `height` as parent element, `opacity` to `0`, and `position` to `absolute`, with `top` set to parent element `.ingConf` `top` value

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
.imgConf {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.imgConf>label {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 250, 205, 0.5);
  margin-top: 40%;
  width: 80px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.imgConf input {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='imgConf' id='toDrop'>
Click or drop image here
<input type="file" accept="image/*" id='fileImg' name="profilePh">
  </div>
  <script>
var obje = document.getElementById('toDrop');
var fileDoor = document.getElementById('fileImg');

function imgLoad(eve) {
  var fil = new FileReader();
  fil.onload = function(ev) {
    obje.style.backgroundImage = `url(${ev.target.result})`;
  }
  fil.readAsDataURL(eve.target.files[0] || eve.dataTransfer.files[0]);
}
fileDoor.onchange = imgLoad;
fileDoor.ondrop = imgLoad;
fileDoor.ondragover = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
}
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd supposed to see the error. Thanks